# PyCharm: defining tab snippet completion for Jinja 2 include tag

Tags: pycharm, jinja2

If using Sublime text and [Djaneiro](https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro) package you get nice tab autocompletion for Jinja/Django template tags and filter e.g. `include` (type in include + press tab):

[image]

PyCharm claims to support for Jinja templates and has nice syntax coloring. However even though Jinja template support is activate, the tab snippet autocompletion doesn't behave as desird. Typing `include` + tab results to the creation of `<include></include>` XML tag:

[image]

How one can override this in PyCharm, so that snippet tab completion would for for `{% include %}`, `{% extends %}`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm does offer tag name completion inside tags: if you type `{%` manually, PyCharm will then offer completion for Jinja2 tag names as well as their parameters (for example, the path in `{% include %}`.

If you want to insert an `{% include %}` tag when you type 'include' and press Tab, you can do so by defining a live template (PyCharm | Preferences | Live Templates).